# ReactNative - Simulator works, iPhone crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

First app development in ReactNative. I just started to load data in via API and now the App crashes on my phone - but works fine in the simulator. The only errors I have (nothing in console) are from xCode, see image:

[image]

Any help debugging / fixing this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have any developer configurations?

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue because I was running 8.2 in simulator and 10.2 on my phone. 10.2 does not allow you to fetch using http, only https.